# CSS: 3 divs with atypical wrapping

Tags: css, html, css-float, word-wrap

I'm trying to accomplish some atypical div behavior, so I'm not sure if this is possible.

I have three divs which sit next to one another horizontally: A, B, and C (from left to right). When the browser is resized, or if a user's browser window is too small, I would like div B to drop below div A, rather than the typical behavior where div C drops below div A.

The typical behavior is demonstrated by this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Title
    </title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .box {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 4px;
            background: #ccc;
            width: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box" style="height: 200px;">div a</div>
    <div class="box" style="height: 300px;">div b</div>
    <div class="box" style="height: 500px;">div c</div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P5xLx/

When I place divs A and B in one table-cell and div C in another, I can get div B to drop below div A. The only issue with this is that the left table-cell which contains the two divs does not collapse to the width of the two divs, and so there is still a gap between divs A and B and div C. This code shows that behavior:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Title
    </title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .box {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 4px;
            background: #ccc;
            width: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="display: table;">
        <div style="display: table-row;">
            <div style="display: table-cell;">
                <div class="box" style="height: 200px;">div a</div>
                <div class="box" style="height: 300px;">div b</div>
            </div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;">
                <div class="box" style="height: 500px;">div c</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cncgs/

Is there a way to make the left table-cell take the width of the two stacked divs, or maybe there is some other way to accomplish this which doesn't involve the table at all. Basically, I just need to find a way for div C to sit next to A and B once B drops below A. I'm trying to find a css solution and avoid using a javascript solution which, for example, calculates the width of A and B and compares it to the width of the left table-cell.

**EDIT** In the examples above, the widths are 200px, but in the actual implementation, that 200px is a variable width, depending on user-submitted content. I'm looking for a solution which can deal with variable-width columns.

Answer (score 1):

How does this suit? Using media queries to change the width of the container for the first two divs:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .box {
            display: block;
            margin: 4px;
            background: #ccc;
            width: 200px;
            float:left;
        }
        .leftCol{width:416px; float:left}

        @media screen and (max-width: 1000px){
            .leftCol{width:208px;}
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="leftCol">
        <div class="box" style="height: 200px;">div a</div>
        <div class="box" style="height: 300px;">div b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box" style="height: 500px;">div c</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously the widths will vary depending on what you’re building.

Comment: Ok, now we're getting somewhere. I never realized you could specify browser dimensions on a media query. Now, my question is there a way to adapt this to a situation where the divs' widths are variable? For the sake of simplicity, I gave them fixed widths in the example, but in the actual implementation, their widths vary based on their content.

Comment: I see that it is possible to specify a range of min and max width, but the content in the divs will be user generated, so I have no way of knowing how wide they will be...

Comment: Im not sure you can do what you're asking with just CSS. It would probably be fine if you knew that the column width could be set (even if it were a percentage).

Have you thought about using something like jQuery Masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/

It would probably be far more robust than some CSS hack.
Also there is a CSS way to make something like Masonry but relies on a known width and CSS3.

http://sickdesigner.com/index.php/2011/html-css/masonry-css-getting-awesome-with-css3/

Answer (score 0):

This might be close to what you want

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Title
    </title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .box {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 4px;
            background: #ccc;
            width: 200px;
        }
        .left { float: left; }
        .right {float: right;}
        .wrap {max-width: 625px; overflow:auto;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="box left" style="height: 200px;">div a</div>
        <div class="box right" style="height: 500px;">div c</div>
        <div class="box" style="height: 300px;">div b</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MR6fj/

The only problem is div c stays all the way to the right of the wrap div all the time. This might be closer to what you wanted though.